# Control the form submission based on the API response

Tags: javascript, html, forms, api

I want to submit my form depending on the API response.

If the API response is valid, submit the form if not, don't submit and don't reload the page until the response is valid

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" class="myForm" id="myFormID" onsubmit="return getResult()">

   <button id="if-submit" type="submit">Submit</button></div>


function getResult(){

function makeGetRequest(path) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        axios.get(path).then(
            (response) => {
                var result = response.data;
                resolve(result);
            },
                (error) => {
                reject(error);
            }
        );
    });
}


    async function main() {
        var emailAdd = (document.getElementById('inf_field_Email').value);
        if (emailAdd != ""){ 

            var result = await makeGetRequest(server+emailAdd);
            let form = document.getElementById('myFormID');

            if (result.status == 'valid'){
                form.action = "https://nextpage.com";
                return true;

            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        else{

            console.log('Please put email address')
        }
    }

    main();


}
```

I have this code, however, it just reloading after I click the submit button

Answer (score 0):

With `<button type="submit">` the page will always load. Use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp) method to block the reload action and proceed with whenever action you wanted after that.